Hibernation is locking the screen instead after upgrading to 24.04 lts
Ive a partition swap disk that was working fine for hibernation before upgrading but now when I hibernate, only the screen turns off for a moment, then I am prompted to sign in again. Here is a log from the system:
Jun 20 18:41:10 momen-XPS-13 systemd[1]: Starting systemd-hibernate.service - Hibernate...
Jun 20 18:41:10 momen-XPS-13 systemctl[7860]: Call to Hibernate failed: There's already a shutdown or sleep operation in progress
Jun 20 18:41:10 momen-XPS-13 systemd[1]: systemd-hibernate.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 20 18:41:10 momen-XPS-13 systemd[1]: systemd-hibernate.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 20 18:41:10 momen-XPS-13 systemd[1]: Failed to start systemd-hibernate.service - Hibernate.


I tried running systemctl list-jobs  but it says there are no jobs running
here are my configurations:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=/dev/sda2"
and output of sudo nano /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume  is RESUME=UUID=f5cc4c0c-dbef-4151-b3a1-230a3be29795 
output of blkid | grep "swap" is /dev/sda2: UUID="f5cc4c0c-dbef-4151-b3a1-230a3be29795" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="8d795db4-60c0-47a4-9807-07839a4906e1" 

From your title instead of what?

Instead of hibernating (suspend to disk)
